# Play Framwork Java Angular - redirect to html page

Tags: java, angularjs, scala, playframework

I have a ToDoController.java and the method

```
public static Result getAllToDos() {

     return ok(index.render("Your new application is also ready."));
    }
```

How can i redirect the page to ToDo.html using Play framework.
I am trying to write an application using Angular/Java/Play

My route file

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()


GET     /            controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="index.html")



GET     /todo                          controllers.ToDoController.getAllToDos()
```

Comment: I think Daniels answer is not working due to the fact that you hardcoded / with index.html.
Instead you mihgt use a variable on the path and use that as file argument (see The URI Pattern in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting). However I think that this http://pauldijou.fr/blog/2013/02/17/angularjs-routing-playframework/
might help u to understand routing in play! along with routing in AngularJS. Hope that helps,
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
public static Result getAllToDos() {
  return redirect("/ToDo.html");
}
```

Comment: Where is your ToDo.html route declaration? Please explain what you are trying to do more briefly. Your route file looks like something is missing. if your controller is named ToDoController then there's a mistake in the route. It should be controllers.ToDoController.getAllToDos()  instead of controllers.ToDo.getAllToDos()

Comment: I am trying to write an application with Angular as front end using Play framework in Java .Yeah my my controller name is TodoController. So when I call http://localhost:9000/todo it should show me my todo.html

Comment: Could you please clarify where the ToDo.html is located? If I had understood your comment correctly all you want to do is display a view template for the */todo* route.